# Derivative of function defined by integral of different variable

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have the following exercise which I certainly have gotten no clue about it.

> Let F(t) be defined: $F(t) = \int_{tan(t)}^{\sqrt{t^2+1}} e^{-tx^2}dx$
>
> What is $F'(0)$?

I have no clue about what subjects this relates to.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Formal_statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Differentiation under the integral sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)

$$F'(t)={ e }^{ -t\left( { t }^{ 2 }+1 \right)  }\frac { t }{ \sqrt { { t }^{ 2 }+1 }  } -{ e }^{ -t\tan { t }  }\frac { 1 }{ \cos ^{ 2 }{ t }  } +\int _{ 
tan(t) }^{ \sqrt { t^{ 2 }+1 }  } \frac { \delta  }{ \delta t } \left( e^{ -tx^{ 2 } } \right) dx=\\ ={ e }^{ -t\left( { t }^{ 2 }+1 \right)  }\frac { t }{ \sqrt { { t }^{ 2 }+1 }  } -{ e }^{ -t\tan { t }  }\frac { 1 }{ \cos ^{ 2 }{ t }  } +\int _{ tan(t) }^{ \sqrt { t^{ 2 }+1 }  } -{ x }^{ 2 }{ e }^{ -{ tx }^{ 2 } }dx$$

$$F'(0)={ e }^{ -t\left( { t }^{ 2 }+1 \right)  }\frac { t }{ \sqrt { { t }^{ 2 }+1 }  } -{ e }^{ -t\tan { t }  }\frac { 1 }{ \cos ^{ 2 }{ t }  } +\int _{ tan(t) }^{ \sqrt { t^{ 2 }+1 }  } \frac { \delta  }{ \delta t } \left( e^{ -tx^{ 2 } } \right) dx=\\ =0-1-\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ { x }^{ 2 } } dx=-1-\frac { 1 }{ 3 } =-\frac { 4 }{ 3 } $$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Use Leibniz rule of differentiation under integration

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign